# can't find max number of a list with sublist in python

Tags: python, list, numbers, append, max

i have two lists:

1. `list1=[1,2,3]`
2. `list2=[4,5,6]`

after using append: `list1[1,2,3,[4,5,6]]`

I want to print max number of list1 and sublist. I've tried this:

```
print("MAX:",max(list1))
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `max(list1), max(list2)` ?

Comment: i want to find max only using list1 if it's possible ,without compare max from list1 and list2

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want the max of list1, why not get it before appending it to another list. Looks like this is an XY problem.

Comment: i can do that obviously, but i want that for a homework that requires to find max of list1 after use append on list2 with list1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, correctly you want to find the maximum after flattening the list, do:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]


result = max(ei for e in list1 for ei in (e if isinstance(e, list) else [e]))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
6
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're printing max of something with a reference called "list", I only see "list1" and "list2".
If you were calling on list1 then the error is that you can't compare an int and a list. Since max() uses operator "<"
Keep in mind that you appended list2, so it's the last element of list1 or list1[-1].
If you're trying to print list1's max and list2's max then write:

```
print("MAX:",max(list1[0:-1]))       #passes list1 without last element    
print("MAX of SUBLIST:", max(list1[-1]))      #list2 is last element of list1
```

This should print max int of each list assuming you're only appending 1 list to list1 and list2 has no sublists.

If you're trying to create one list with elements of list1 and list2 do this by doing:

```
list1 += list2
```

Answer (score 0):

So I see two easy options here.  The first one would be to use extend instead of append.  So you would do:

```
list1.extend(list2)
```

Then your list1 will be [1,2,3,4,5,6] and the rest of your code will work.  Your other option would be to do something like:

```
print("MAX:{}".format(max([max(x) for x in list1]))
```

Which should reduce the sublist to just it's maximum value and then you should be able to print.  This will only work if it is nested one deep like your example.

Answer (score 0):

Max doesn't work because there is no equality test between an int and a list.
If you want to test the int values in list 1 only, you can do:

```
print(max([item for item in list1 if isinstance(item, int)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `append`, use `+=` or `extend`, i.e.:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list1 += list2
# list1.extend(list2)

print(max(list1))
# 6
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/4008f300c6)